# Using paraview filters in Python, Paraview python api

Tags: vtk, paraview

I have been using Paraview to visualize and analyse VTU files. I find the calculate gradient filter quite useful. I would like to know if there is a python API for Paraview which I can use to use this filter.

I'm looking for something like this.

```
import paraview as pv

MyFile = "Myfile0001.vtu"

Divergence = pv.filters.GradientOfUnstructuredDataset.(Myfile)
```

Comment: For posterity, the discussion about it on the [ParaView forum](https://discourse.paraview.org/t/calculate-the-divergence-of-a-vector-field-using-paraview-filter/6617)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ParaView is fully [scriptable in python](https://docs.paraview.org/en/latest/UsersGuide/introduction.html#getting-started-with-pvpython). Each part of this doc has a 'do it in python' version.

Whereas API doc does not necessary exist, you can use the [Python Trace](https://docs.paraview.org/en/latest/UsersGuide/introduction.html?highlight=trace#tracing-actions-for-scripting) (in Tool menu), that records action from the GUI and save it as a python script.

*EDIT*

To get back data as an array, it needs some additional steps as ParaView works on a client/server mode. You should [Fetch](https://docs.paraview.org/en/latest/ReferenceManual/parallelDataVisualization.html?highlight=fetch#fetching-data-to-the-client) the data and then you can manipulate the vtkObject, extract the array and convert it to numpy.

Something like

```py
from paraview.simple import *
from vtk.numpy_interface import dataset_adapter as dsa

gridvtu = XMLUnstructuredGridReader(registrationName='grid', FileName=['grid.vtu'])
gradient = GradientOfUnstructuredDataSet(registrationName='Gradient', Input=gridvtu)
vtk_grid = servermanager.Fetch(gradient)
wraped_grid = dsa.WrapObject(vtk_grid)
divergence_array = wraped_grid.PointData["Divergence"]
```

Note that `divergence_array` is a numpy.ndarray

You also can write pure vtk code, as in [this example on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38504907/reading-a-vtk-polydata-file-and-converting-it-into-numpy-array)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. However, it does not answer my question. What I'm looking for is a way to calculate the divergence if I have a vector array.

Comment: I mean, to pass the VTU file and the field as an argument and get the divergence back as an array.

Comment: It was not clear that you want to manipulate the resulting array. I updated my answer